# How to call an instance method whose name is in a string?

Tags: javascript

I want to call the instance methods whose name is passed with the `func` input element but my code fails because it can't find the `TestClass` instance methods in the global `window`. How can I achieve this?

```js
class TestClass {
  func = document.getElementById('func');

  result = document.getElementById('result');

  func1 = () => {
    this.result.innerHTML = 'func1 called';
  };

  func2() {
    this.result.innerHTML = 'func2 called';
  }

  funcListener = () => {
    window[this.func.value]();
  };

  constructor() {
    this.func.addEventListener('change', this.funcListener);
  }
}

new TestClass();
```

```html
functest.html

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>functest</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="func" placeholder="enter function to call: func1, func2" type="text" maxlength="200">
  <label id="result" for="func">result</label>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window[this.func.value]()` - your functions are wrapped inside class, not global, so use `this[this.func.value]()` instead.

```js
class TestClass {
  func = document.getElementById('func');

  result = document.getElementById('result');

  func1 = () => {
    this.result.innerHTML = 'func1 called';
  };

  func2() {
    this.result.innerHTML = 'func2 called';
  }

  funcListener = () => {
    this[this.func.value]();
  };

  constructor() {
    this.func.addEventListener('change', this.funcListener);
  }
}

new TestClass();
```

```html
functest.html

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>functest</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="func" placeholder="enter function to call: func1, func2" type="text" maxlength="200">
  <label id="result" for="func">result</label>
</body>
```